# Manually creating intermediate table in a many to many relationship for Core - Data

Tags: iphone, sql, core-data

I'm currenty working with Core-data for an iPhone project.

But I'm a bit confused about one element.

With *Core Data* currently you do not need to create the intermediate table when creating *many to many relationships* (its all handled behind the scenes by core data)

**But in my case I actually need some attributes on my many to many relationship!**

For example

I have a table called `Students`
and another table called `Lessons`

a `Student` can be in many `lessons`
and a `lesson` can have many `students`

Now a standard many to many relationship will not work for me as I actually need to define more details on the join, i.e. `StartDate` and `LeaveDate`.

In a standard sql model for example my join table would be something like

```
StudentLessons (Studentid, LessonId, StartDate, LeaveDate )
```

I would need these properties as when i'm querying for information I will need the details from the join to filter my results.

**How can I create this in core data and also filter for results?**

I've seen folks say that you would actually create the `StudentLesson` entity manually in core data.

**Now if I did this would I just have the attributes (Startdate, LeaveDate) and then a one to many relationship from the Student and then the Lessons table?**

```
Student - > StudentLessons
Lesson - > StudentLessons
```

I guess I'm a bit confused on how I would go about making sure that the relationships and the content of the relationships are setup correctly. (i.e If I add an `Student` object to the `StudentLessons` - how would I then assign/add the `Lesson`.)

Sorry this is my first time playing with Core Data.

Takes a bit o getting used to when coming from a full on sql background.

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right. The correct way to do this is to create a **new entity** like *StudentLessons*. Let's call it *Attendance*. It should have the `startDate` and `endDate`, and two relationships.

The relationship to the student can be many-to-many, unless it is foreseeable that startDate and endDate are always different for each student. One *Attendance* with its dates can have many students in it. One student can have several *Attendance* duties.

`Student <<---->> Attendance`

Clearly, the relationship to *Lesson* should be one-to-many. One *Lesson* can have different *Attendance* configurations, with different dates. But each *Attendance* belongs only to one *Lesson*.

`Lesson <---->> Attendance`

To address your question, you can make the *Attendance* attribute of *Lesson* non-optional (and vice versa), this way it will ensure that each *Lesson* has at least one *Attendance* with appropriate dates, and each *Attendance* has exactly one *Lesson*.

I think your can remove the link between *Student* and *Lesson*. Just assign an *Attendance* rather than a lesson. If you want a *Lesson* assigned to a *Student* without dates, just allow *Attendance* to have `NULL` as those properties.

Answer (score 1):

TheTiger,

Just because Core Data will create a join table for you, that doesn't mean you have to use it. Maintaining which student succeeds with which lesson is just the same except you will create the intermediate entity and then use the appropriate setters to build the relationships.

You will have to use more key paths and do relationship prefetching but those are straightforward to do.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks Andrew  - any examples of these techniques available? (again new to core data... )

Comment: There are plenty of examples on Apple's web site. Core Data will push your knowledge of Objective-C. Hence, it can have a large learning curve. I recommend that you get one of the several books on Core Data. Apple's tutorial and programming guide are also worth reading cover to cover.